# Calling python from R's system(): pandas not found

Tags: python, r, pandas, system

I inherited a (awful) project in which R systematically calls Python scripts by means of R's `system()`.

I know this is quite a bad practice, but I honestly don't have the time to remediate it.

The issue is, I had to migrate to a new machine, having no documentation as to how to configure the machine, and now, if I call `python3.8 "myscript.py" "arg1" "arg2"` it imports pandas flawlessly.
When I do (from R) `system(paste("python3.8"," ","myscript.py"," ",arg1," ",arg2),,wait=TRUE)`, the script fails at `import pandas as pd`.

I even try to encapsulate the `python3.8 "myscript.py" "arg1" "arg2"` into `myscriptcaller.sh` and call (from R) `system(paste("python3.8"," ","myscriptcaller.sh"," ",arg1," ",arg2),,wait=TRUE)`, with same results.

I'm confused and desperate. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is sys.path different between the two calls

Comment: No, it is not different

Comment: Actually, weird... I erased the machine (Ubuntu 20), created a new one (Ubuntu 16), downgraded to R 3.4.4 and this behaviour is gone...

Comment: Even more weird: in a brand new Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot reproduce this strange behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to verify if you are using the same python in R and in the system with `"which python"`, in case they are not the same run

```
system(paste("full/path/python"," ", "myscript.py"," ",arg1," ",arg2),,wait=TRUE)
```

Comment: I did specify /usr/bin/python3.8. Notably, I don't have any other python installations in that machine